# how to use the pts in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, display, pts

I have a library with can provide video data and PTS. The library head file Like this：

```
 /**
 * \brief           Write mirror video H.264 frame to player.
 * \param p_src     Pointer to source buffer.
 * \param size      H.264 frame size. (unit: byte)
 * \param ptsValue  PTS value.
 * \return          Copied size. (unit: byte)
 */
int (*WriteMirrorVideoData)(const std::string& ip, const void *p_src, int size, double ptsValue);
```

As you see, the library give me video frame buffer address and PTS.

I use FFMpeg to decode video data correctly.

My question is how to control the display time by ptsValue which provided by library.

Did I need to set the ptsValue to AVFrame? then FFMPeg can control the display time itself.
Or I need to control the display by my own code?

I am a newer to FFMpeg. please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Presentation timestamp info is included in video file usually. FFmpeg will set it when decoding. It's just a data field in AVFrame/AVPacket structs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I know normally PTS info is included in video file. But  in my project, the video data is from buffer, and PTS value is not included in video data buffer, it is provided alonely.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question with you,you should init an Avpackt and set the pts = yourpts(from libary), before set value you may need to use av_rescale_q to disposal the value. this is my code

```
    for(int i =0; i < packets.size(); i++){
        AVStream* st = fmtCtx->streams[vi];
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.stream_index = st->index;
        pkt.data = packet.data();
        pkt.size = packet.size;
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(Mypts[i] - Mypts[0], st->time_base,
                           AVRational{1, 20});
        pkt.duration = 0;
        pkt.pos = -1;
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmtCtx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
             printf("cannot write frame");
        }
    }
```

I use dxgi to get frame so my pts is from struct DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO::LastPresentTime. i also have a question, when i use av_rescale_q i set the last parm AVRational{1, 20},i do not know why,when i init AVCodecContext i have set timebase AVRational{1, 30},but there if i use 30 the answer is not support.
I hope my answer helps you

Comment: i have solved my problem, i use dxgi to get the frame, the LastPresentTime's timebase is us, so when i init my instream timebase should set{1,10000000}, and then when i write the packets in to outstream should set pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(Mypts[i] - Mypts[0], st->time_base, AVRational{1, 10000000});